# Convert the given time into milliseconds

Tags: java, javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to convert the time (hh:mm:ss) into milliseconds. How could i do it?

Is it right to use the following one?

hh * mm * ss * 1000;

But if the minute is 00 or second is 00, it gives 0.

How do I calculate this?

Comment: That's a bizarre set of tags to use - where are you actually trying to do this? In Java? In Javascript, possibly with the aid of JQuery? In PHP? Or in SalesForce? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am surprised that you don't understand how a clock works. You should know how many minutes in an hour, how many seconds in a minute. With knowledge you have, you should be able to work it out.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
hrsSec=hh*60*60;// for seconds;
minSec=mm*60;// for seconds;
secSec=ss;// already seconds;
totalSec=(hrsSec+minSec+secSec);// total seconds
milliSec=totalSec*1000; // milliseconds
```

**Also** if you understand the procedure then comment of @Peter Lawrey is noticeable and in short you can try this,

```
milliSec=((hh × 60 + mm) × 60 + ss) × 1000
```

Comment: +1 try ((h × 60 + m) × 60 + sec) × 1000

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes I can but it was necessary to explain every `seconds` for `hours`, `minutes`, otherwise this question is not for `SO`

Comment: The reason I mention this approach is that if you include days and milliseconds the formula can get pretty complicated.

Answer (score 1):

(hh * 3600 + mm * 60 + ss) * 1000;

Answer (score 0):

```
1h == 60min
1min == 60sec
1sec == 1000ms

(ss + (mm + (hh * 60) ) * 60 ) * 1000
```